# UIWebview editable but lost curser and not able to type text in IOS7 but working fine in IOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have loaded html in Webview and make it editable.

```
NSString *htmlStrToShow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body contenteditable =\"true\">%@</body>",htmlStrToShow];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlStrToShow baseURL:nil];
```

I also used,

```
 [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@" document.body.contentEditable =\"true\"; document.designMode=\"on\";"];
```

but when i tried to edit Keyboard is shown but curser is lost and not able to edit. Code is working proper in IOS6 but not working in IOS 7.

Comment: Can you post a little more code?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. In my situation solution was to reduce UIWebView's frame height to safari-like height.